# Записать значения в cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

Вообще не понимаю, в чём ошибка, но cookie вроде как остаётся совершенно пустым.

```
let name = prompt('Как тебя зовут?');
document.cookie = 'Name =' + name +';';
document.cookie = "login=Ivan;";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Comment: Да нет, вроде всё работает: https://jsfiddle.net/je3kmxbp/

Comment: @Yaant , по вашей ссылке у меня тоже выводит, но при открытии файлика с кодом в браузере абсолютно ничего нет

Comment: Это значит, что проблема не в этом коде, а где-то еще

Comment: @Yaant , я уже кажется поняла, в чём. Если запустить тот же код хотя бы в IE, то всё работает. Значит, проблема хрома

Comment: Да в хроме-то этот код сам по себе тоже работает. Может, какое-то из установленных у Вас расширений как-то влияет.

Comment: @Nastya: Если писать в консоли для новой(пустой) вкладки, то ничего не происходит. А если для какой-нибуть открытой страницы - то все нормально. Вывод - нужно для куки прописывать путь и домен, для которых она будет доступна. Посмотрите http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie